# Email Client for Linux and Android

Tags: android, email, crossplatform

I have just made the switch from Windows to Ubuntu. This was after finding out how much Microsoft saves of my information.

Anyway, I was using Outlook for all emails and calendar appointments on Windows 10 and my Android device. I have spent so many hours looking the same program / app for Linux.

My question is, is there an email client for linux desktop and also same provider for Android app. I don't mind paying, I would just like to have the same email client on both Linux and Android.

If anyone could help me that would be great.

Comment: I would no longer use a platform based mail system. Use an online mail; and with android I'd say: google mail.

Comment: @Rinzwind Having Google store your data is arguably even worse than Microsoft.

Comment: No it is not. And since you own an android device a moot point.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the email client that comes pre-installed with every Ubuntu.

Comment: I failed to find a trustworthy answer for the same question. The best option you have on Ubuntu is Thunderbird, which is not available on Android. You can try using outlook on Android and Thunderbird on Ubuntu. That's as close as we can get with trustworthy names at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The only thing is I'm looking for a complete boycott of all Microsoft apps. What was good is if I made an entry to the outlook calendar it would sync with my phone too. But there doesn't seem to be a program that will do that for Linux and android.